# Difficult Differential Equation StreamPlot Problem

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

I understand how to make streamplots and all of that but doing it for this differential equation confuses me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems there's an $=$ that ought to be somewhere in there.

Answer (score 1):

For illustrative purposes:

```
sp = StreamPlot[{1, 26 y (1 - y)}, {t, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
sol = y /. 
   ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == 26 y[t] (1 - y[t]), y[0] == a}, 
    y, {t, 0, 1}, a];
Manipulate[
 Show[sp, Plot[Evaluate[sol[a][t]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> Full], 
  Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, a}]}], {a, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamPlot[{t, 26 y[t] (1 - y[t])}, {t, 0, 10}, {y[t], 0, 10} ]
```

Is this what you're looking for?